# js regex allow dot dash but don't allow side by side

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regex which allows `.-`,numeric and lowercase in string

but those special characters should not come side by side,first,last

I tried this `var re = /^[a-z0-9]+(-.[a-z0-9]+)*$/;` but this allows special characters side by side

the following should be true

`foo.bar`
`foo-bar`
`foo.bar-test`
`f-b-123`

and the following should be false

`foo..bar`
`foo.-bar`
`foo--bar`
`-f`
`f-`

any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fairly close, you can use:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]+)*$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM1cN5/2)

Answer (score 2):

You were very close!

`var re = /^[a-z0-9]+([-.][a-z0-9]+)*$/;`